# How to call a script from one file location in another bash script

Tags: linux, scripting

I have a script named `initTEST.ora` at `location $ORACLE_HOME/dbs`. I want to call `initTEST.ora` script in another script named `test.sh` which is present in `/home/oracle/script`.

Comment: What did you try and what was the result?

Answer (score 0):

You have three options:

1. Set the `PATH` variable to include `$ORACLE_HOME/dbs` in your shell initialization scripts.

   ```
   export PATH="$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/dbs"
   ```

   You may then call the `initTEST.ora` in your `test.sh` by just saying

   ```
   initTEST.ora
   ```
2. Set the PATH variable *in the script*, and then call `initTEST.ora` as above:

   ```
   PATH="$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/dbs"
   initTEST.ora
   ```

   This has the advantage of not modifying the `PATH` variable for your other applications or your interactive shell sessions.
3. Call the `initTEST.ora` script with an absolute path in your `test.sh` script:

   ```
   $ORACLE_HOME/dbs/initTEST.ora
   ```

If I didn't need to access any other scripts in `$ORACLE_HOME/dbs` in my test script, I would probably go with that last option.

If my test script was going to call other scripts from the same Oracle directory, I would go with the second option.

If I often used scripts from the Oracle directory, even in interactive sessions, I would go with the first option above.

If I wanted to share the script with others and wanted to make sure that they pick up `initTEST.ora` from the right location, I would not use the first option, or at least also use one of the other options.